# Grails out of memory exception during Bootstrap.groovy init() - how to load after start but outside Bootstrap init()

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

I have a Grails application that requires a lot of data to be generated and loaded into a graph database.  At present, I'm putting the loading method in a Service and then calling this service from Bootstrap.groovy's init().

import com.example.BootstrapService

```
class BootStrap {

    def bootstrapService // this is my service


    def init = { servletContext ->
        bootstrapService.init()
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

The loading code takes quite a while (minutes) and I am seeing Out of Memory exceptions when starting the application.

However, if I wrap the bootstrapService.init() method in a controller and then call it after the program is started, the Grails application starts ok and the init() method runs without errors.

I therefore believe that Grails must be doing a lot of other things at the same time as init(), and this is tipping the memory requirements over the edge.  Is there a way of getting a method to fire after program launch?  (Obviously I could increase the memory requirements, but the application is to run on EC2, so I want the memory requirements to be as small as possible to keep the costs down).

Comment: Services are transactional, so hibernate will keep all in the session until the end of the service method ejection, that can be the reason of the Out of Memory. Try with " static transactional = false" in your service. If you are still seeing out of memory errors, try to separate your init in "steps" and flush the session between them

Comment: I've got the service as non-transactional, but still see the errors.  What do you mean by "flush the session between them" please?

Comment: You could possibly use the [Spring Tasks API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) to schedule a service method to be invoked.

Comment: Use this 3 lines for flush the session: sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()
DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP.get().clear()